# How can i set alert page style with Response.Write("<script>alert('Center Page')</script>")

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, alert

I work with asp.net webpage project and call alert script  but it's top of page how can set style of alert page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1NnK.png)

Comment: You cannot style the alert box, because that's a system object

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style alert box since its a system object and is not supported to add CSS on it. What you can do is create an html element modal box that will imitate the alert box. You can do this with JQuery or Bootstrap. For reference you can check it here:

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will work fine :

https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert